# How to move up a UIScrollView when keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, keyboard

Update:

my question is: how to prevent the scrollview being reset to the position when clicking on another textfield?

Actually I've tried several ways, such as the solution to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present).

Originally, my scrollView (multiple textfield and textview in it, and all of positions are placed in storyboard) is at the position (0, 302). When the keyboard appears, I wanna move it up to (0, 100). Firstly, I tried to add a button and do the following, it works.

```
CGRect frame = self.informationScrollView.frame;
frame.origin.y = 100;
self.informationScrollView.frame = frame;
```

Then I tried to do the same code in the selector of UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, but it failed. I found the position are always reset even when the activity textField has changed. Can anyone tell me how to prevent the app reseting the position? Thanks a lot.

Comment: why dont you try content offset of scrollview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CGRect frame = self.informationScrollView.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                 self.informationScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake (frame.origin.x,
                                                                 frame.origin.y, 
                                                                 frame.size.width, 
                                               <change height as per requirement>);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

For Multiple TextFields:

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, what I wanna change is frame.origin.y

Comment: Update frame values as per your requirements, that was just an example code. In your case, give Y value as (frame.origin.y - <padding>)

Comment: Yes, it works at start. But when I click on another textField, the scrollView goes back to the original position (as set in storyboard), how can I prevent it?

Comment: In this scenario, i would suggest you to do another thing. Check my update in answer.

Comment: I also pasted the link at my question.

Answer (score 3):

If ypu are using a UIScrollView then, you should take a look in [TPAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding). Its easy to use and give the expected result. You just have to set TPAvoidingScrollView as your UIScrollView's superclass and everything will be taken care of by TPScrollView. JUST TRY IT. HOPE THIS HELPS.

Comment: Moar upvotes for this, please.  Trivially easy drop-in, very permissive license -- no reason not to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple Use this into your `viewDidLoad` method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

and write a code for scrollView against keyboard height inside that

```
-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y, kbSize.height+100, 0);
self.scrollViewChildDetail.contentInset = contentInsets;
self.scrollViewChildDetail.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

-(void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification
{
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.scrollViewChildDetail.contentInset = contentInsets;
self.scrollViewChildDetail.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

it works.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems only moving the content of scrollview up, but not the scrollview.

Comment: yep, it same which you want. its bad programming to move scrollview while keyboard is show. we are set here a content of scrollview not full scrollView.

Comment: But I also wanna move up the scrollView, for at first the content only shows at the bottom of the phone and when the keyboard appears, the keyboard will hide all of the scrollview. Thus I need move up the whole scrollView

Comment: then simply you've set the scrollview frame in above methods.

Comment: Then it's what my problem about. The frame of the scrollView is always reset when clicking on another textField.

Answer (score 1):

Use the best concept of `NSNotificationCenter` which is explained by @Sarat_Patel

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

And handle with local methods:

```
-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification
-(void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Comment: Its same. No need to give answer again and again dear **@DSP**

Answer (score 1):

The best course of action with UIScrollView is to set the **contentInsets** and the **scrollIndicatorInsets** based on the appearance of the keyboard. If the content of the scroll view are your UITextField and UITextView instances, then you should be offsetting the scroll view content via **contentOffset**, not moving the frame of the scroll view.

That being said, if you really need to move the scroll view and its bouncing back, it's probably something to do with the layout constraints.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should read more examples since I'm new to iOS developing and not so familiar with contentInsets, scrollIndicatorInsets and contentOffset. What I can do is ti copy the code from examples from 'Managing The Keyboard: Text Programming Guide' but not know why the code is that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Official Apple Approved approach: [Managing The Keyboard: Text Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1)

However, I would recommend if you are using Autolayout, that you use a constraint to manage the space between the `UITextView` and the bottom of the screen and programatically change it's constant value to match that of the height of the keyboard via the keyboard show notification mentioned in the above article and other solutions here. This is because you can receive multiple keyboard show notifications with different heights, which can break if you try and toggle the view frame.